# string.indexOf() Получение массива индексов

Tags: android, строки, indexof

Если в какой-либо строке, например, этой:

```
String str = "1аааа1ааа1";
```

содержится несколько подстрок "1", то indexOf вернёт только одно значение (первое совпадение).

```
int i = str.indexOf("1");
//i = 0
```

Есть ли способ получить массив значений indexOf, не удаляя (изменяя ) строки (или StringBuilder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте в цикле метод [indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))
Начинайте каждый раз искать с индекса, который на 1 больше того, что вы получили на предыдущей итерации. Полученные индексы записывайте в массив до тех пор, пока не получите в результате -1.

https://ideone.com/mV1Lhv

```
String str = "1аааа1ааа1"; 
ArrayList<Integer> inds = new ArrayList<>();
int index = str.indexOf("1");
while (index != -1) {
    inds.add(index);
    index = str.indexOf("1", index + 1);
}
for (int ind : inds) {
    System.out.println(ind);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я не знаю, как это делать, но теперь я знаю, в каком направлении мыслить :)

Comment: Что вам непонятно? Я же описал алгоритм. Сейчас набросаю примерный код.